# How to get and ascribe irregular numbers to objects?

Tags: python

I am a beginner and I have a question.
I have datas in csv file, I can find 100 objects and irregular number of size number for each object. In one row I have a name of the object, its size and then these irregular numbers- for one name it can be 20 of then and for the other 40.

```
import glob
import csv
import re
for f_name in glob.glob("*.csv"):
with open(f_name) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,  delimiter=',')
    for row in reader: 
       print (row[1])
```

how can I have the numbers which are irregular? any loop? and how can I ascribe the numbers to the "size" and "name"?

Comment: can you provide sample of some lines in your file and the result you want for this

Comment: you can just do `name = row[0]`, `size = row[1]` & `data = row[2:]`

Comment: @armak It is:                                                                           name,Kasia (enter)
weight,45 (enter)
No,Size(enter)
1,2.046348(enter)
2,2.160691  (enter)and I would like to have something like Kasia as the index and her size. but all datas are stored like this with irregular number of the size. Sorry, I don't know how to edit it in a comment so enter means it's in the next line

Comment: @mishakisha what about the spaces between `Kasia weight` are those next lines??

Comment: @armak they are under each other: name,Kasia it one line, weight,45 is the second one and so on. there are no spaces between that

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I can't because when I write name=row[0] I get not only the name, but also the numbers, that's the problem

Comment: @mishakisha it means you want all the data corresponding to `Kasia` under one row and same follows for the next name which will come after all those irregular numbers. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @armak  I want to have name as the index and `Kasia` as the data and as the second index I want to have weight and the number (45 in this case) and then I have this irregular numbers that I want to have corresponding to the 3rd index called size

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.csv') as fp:
  for line in fp:
     data = line.split(',')
     if data[0] == 'name':
       result[name] = init_dict(name)
     elif data[0] == 'weight' :
       update_dict(data[1])
     else:
       update_dict(data[0])
```

basically you can just loop through the file and whenever you encounter a name just create a new_dict and update the corresponding attribute until you encounter the new name

```
def init_dict(name):
  return {'name': name, 'weight':None, 'others':None}
```

similary you can write an update dict to update the corresponding attributes of the dict of that corresponding name

Comment: I did something like this (the method is dict.update) and as a result, Spyder shows that all values are assigned to "name"